# C++ : Bizarre Numbers Appearing in Output

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, random

For my school project, I am supposed to fill an array of 20 with random numbers between (about) -10 and 10.  Then, I have to organize these numbers based on whether they are negative, 0, or positive.  I am told to finish off the program printing out the original array, as well as the new array.

For some reason, the organized array prints out random (TYPE:long) numbers in some of the spaces.  I'm not sure why this is the case.  Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
// insert code here...
srand(time(NULL));
int numbers[20], final[20], first = 1, second = 1;

std::cout << "Enter 20 numbers, and without sorting, this program will take them and organize them based on positive, negative, and 0.\n\n";
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    std::cout << "Enter number " << (i+1) << ": ";
    //std::cin >> numbers[i];
    numbers[i] = (rand()%20 -10);
    std::cout << numbers[i] << std::endl;
}

//Numbers lower than 0
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    if(numbers[i] < 0){
        final[i] = numbers[i];
        first++;
    }
}
//Numbers equal to 0
for(int i = first; i < 20; i++){
    if(numbers[i] == 0){
        final[i] = numbers[i];
        second++;
    }
}
//Numbers greater than 0
for(int i = second; i < 20; i++){
    if(numbers[i] == 0){
        final[i] = numbers[i];
    }
}

std::cout << "This is your original array: ";
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    std::cout << numbers[i];
    if(i != 19)
        std::cout << ",";
    std::cout << " ";
    if(i == 19)
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;
}

std::cout << "This your new, organized, array: ";
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    std::cout << final[i];
    if(i != 19)
        std::cout << ",";
    std::cout << " ";
    if(i == 19)
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

My output is this:

```
Enter 20 numbers, and without sorting, this program will take them and organize them based on positive, negative, and 0.

Enter number 1: -6
Enter number 2: 0
Enter number 3: -4
Enter number 4: -5
Enter number 5: 0
Enter number 6: -4
Enter number 7: -5
Enter number 8: -5
Enter number 9: -8
Enter number 10: 5
Enter number 11: 0
Enter number 12: -3
Enter number 13: 5
Enter number 14: -5
Enter number 15: 7
Enter number 16: 2
Enter number 17: 9
Enter number 18: 9
Enter number 19: 3
Enter number 20: 2
This is your original array: -6, 0, -4, -5, 0, -4, -5, -5, -8, 5, 0, -3, 5, -5, 7, 2, 9, 9, 3, 2 


This your new, organized, array: -6, 1879110449, -4, -5, 0, -4, -5, -5, -8, 1, 0, -3, 1606416384, -5, 1606423158, 32767, 1606416416, 32767, 1606416416, 32767"
```

Thank you in advance to all who reply.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Looks like the elements with the unexpected values were never initialized. Also consider working completely in the positive domain and offset by 10 only when presenting to the user.

Comment: Thank you for the offset tip.  My only concern is that the unexpected values were initialized under the 'final[10]' array.  Did I make a mistake initializing them in the for loops?  It seems about right...

Comment: Only final[i] elements are being set where number[i] <= 0.  That's also evident in your output.  You have a copy-n-paste error in the condition where you comment  // Numbers greater than 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not putting the number in the correct `final` array position, check how now `first` is used to mark the position where next element should be put in final array:

Also I removed the unused `second` variable

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
// insert code here...
srand(time(NULL));
// changed first = 1 to first = 0 and eliminated second
int numbers[20], final[20], first = 0;

std::cout << "Enter 20 numbers, and without sorting, this program will take them and organize them based on positive, negative, and 0.\n\n";
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    std::cout << "Enter number " << (i+1) << ": ";
    //std::cin >> numbers[i];
    numbers[i] = (rand()%20 -10);
    std::cout << numbers[i] << std::endl;
}

//Numbers lower than 0
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    if(numbers[i] < 0){
        // now it is put in final[first] instead of final[i] 
        final[first] = numbers[i];
        first++;
    }
}
//Numbers equal to 0
//changed i to start from 0 again
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    if(numbers[i] == 0){
        final[first] = numbers[i];
        first++;
    }
}
//Numbers greater than 0
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    if(numbers[i] > 0){ // Yeah, here was the typo... replaced `==` with `>`
        final[first] = numbers[i];
        // added this increment
        first++;
    }
}

std::cout << "This is your original array: ";
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    std::cout << numbers[i];
    if(i != 19)
        std::cout << ",";
    std::cout << " ";
    if(i == 19)
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;
}

std::cout << "This your new, organized, array: ";
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    std::cout << final[i];
    if(i != 19)
        std::cout << ",";
    std::cout << " ";
    if(i == 19)
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  Unfortunately, the output in the console still displays the bizarre numbers, even with your changes.  Is there a reason for this?  Thanks again.

Comment: check my comment below "The other issue with your code is a typo in the if statement within section //Numbers greater than 0. I'll let you figure that one for yourself :)"

Comment: Yes, there was a == instead of > in numbers greater than 0 loop :), now should run just fine.

Comment: If by typo you mean incorrect spelling, I'm not seeing what you're hinting at.  Are you indirectly telling me that I should change the 'int i = 0' in this section to 'int i = first'?  Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

The indexer for the `final` array should be independently increased from the indexer (`i`) for the `numbers` array. In other words:

```
int idxFinal = 0; // determines where on the 'array' index to insert next

for(int i = first; i < 20; i++){
    if(numbers[i] < 0){
        final[idxFinal] = numbers[i];
        first++;
        idxFinal++;
    }
}

...

//Numbers equal to 0
for(int i = first; i < 20; i++){
    if(numbers[i] == 0){
        final[idxFinal++] = numbers[i];
        second++;
    }
}
```

The other issue with your code is a typo in the `if` statement within section `//Numbers greater than 0`. I'll let you figure that one for yourself :)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!  Just a question though, when would the variable 'second' be used with where you had placed it in your version of the code?

Comment: You only need the variable `first` and `second` if you want to keep track of how many numbers where categorised into the first group (less than 0), and how many in the second group (equal to 0). And I would initialise them to the initial value of zero. If that's not a requirement, then you don't need those two variables

Answer (score 0):

You're getting strange numbers on output because your code doesn't completely fill the array (it prints out the contents that were already on those memory positions).

Without giving out the code (you're almost there):

- You should iterate your `for` loops (all three of them) through the whole array size (0 to 20), remember that during these loops you're trying to check values, so you need to go through all of them.
- Assign to your final array based on your counters (`first`, `second`), and not based on `i`. Again, `i` is just used to loop through the arrays. This causes your arrays to have holes right here. You're only assigning values to `final` when you enter the `if` statements, and only in their respective positions (`i`).
- Your `if` statement for numbers greater than zero is incorrect, it check for equals.
- Initialize `first` and `second` with 0, not 1.

That should do it. As a side note, you don't really need two separate counters, `first` and `second`. You could use just one, incrementing it in your first loop, and then continue incrementing it in your second loop and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  Why though would I iterate the third for loop?  I'm not sure how that would change the output in the console...

Comment: You still need to add values greater than zero to your `final` array. Don't assign to `final[i]`, though. Continue to use your counters, as in `final[second++]` or `final[first++]` if you ditch second at all.